# Changing list to rows in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, computer-science

I joined two data excel sheets together by appending them using python.

I would like to view the list I have appended as rows instead of a list as the actual data I have is quite large.

I would preferably like to move the list to a different excel tab (using python). Where I can view the data in the list as rows instead of a list. is there a python code for this?

**Quarter 1**
Team    Country     Account PRI 10-k    Date    Name
Family  USA 1002    205 Adjusted    Accumulated 3/31/2022   Jess
Chess   Brazil  1001    109 Translation Comprehensive   4/1/2022    Mike
House   Kenya   1003    303 Cumulation  Income  4/2/2022    Phil
Pool    South Africa    1004    404 Translation Other   4/3/2022    John
Club    Turkey  1005    605 Adjusted    Accumulated 4/4/2022    Nick
Easter  France  1006    808 Translation Other   4/5/2022    Joe
Chair   Greece  1007    707 Key attribute   Comprehensive   4/6/2022    Rick
Road    Italy   1008    303 Cumulation  Income  4/7/2022    Tom
Cross   Ethiopia    1010    405 translation Accumulated 4/8/2022    Jill
Soccer  Cuba    1011    808 adjusted    Other   4/9/2022    Matt
Baseball    Singapore   1012    304 adjusted    Comprehensive   4/10/2022   Tim
Basketball  Qatar   1013    102 Translation Income  4/11/2022   Jane

**Quarter 2**
Team    Country     Account PRI 10-k    Date    Name
Family  USA 10002   205 Adjusted    Accumulated 3/31/2022   Jess
Chess   Brazil  1001    109 Translation Comprehensive   4/1/2022    Mike
House   Kenya   1003    303 Cumulation  Income  4/2/2022    Phil
Pool    South Africa    1004    404 Translation Other   4/3/2022    John
Club    Turkey  1005    605 Adjusted    Accumulated 4/4/2022    Nick
Easter  France  1006    808 Translation Other   4/5/2022    Joe
Chair   Greece  1007    707 Key attribute   Comprehensive   4/6/2022    Rick
Road    Italy   1008    303 Cumulation  Income  4/7/2022    Tom
Eagle Eye   Netherlands 1015    208 adjustment  Comprehensive   4/12/2022   Chris

This is the code I have so far and the data I was joining.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o46FL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsOxE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3lJA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX0kn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAgyr.png)

```
import csv
import os
import sys

path_quarter_1 = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Quarter_1.csv")  # path to the csv file
path_quarter_2 = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Quarter_2.csv")  # path to the csv file

# coulmns are:- Team, Country, Account, PRI, 10-k, Date, Name

with open(path_quarter_1, "r") as f:  # opening the csv file
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # creating a reader object
    data_q1 = list(reader)  # converting the reader object to a list for Quarter 1

with open(path_quarter_2, "r") as f:  # opening the csv file
    reader = csv.reader(f)  # creating a reader object
    data_q2 = list(reader)  # converting the reader object to a list for Quarter 2

# Account that are in both quarters
account_in_both = []  # creating a list to store the accounts that are in both quarters
for i in range(1, len(data_q1)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 1
    for j in range(1, len(data_q2)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 2
        if data_q1[i][2] == data_q2[j][2]:  # checking if the accounts are same
            account_in_both.append(data_q1[i][2])  # appending the account to the list
print("Account in both", account_in_both)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line

# In Q1 but not in Q2
account_in_q1_not_q2 = (
    []
)  # creating a list to store the accounts that are in Q1 but not in Q2
for i in range(1, len(data_q1)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 1
    if (
        data_q1[i][2] not in account_in_both
    ):  # checking if the account is not in both quarters
        account_in_q1_not_q2.append(data_q1[i][2])  # appending the account to the list

print("Account in Q1 but not in Q2", account_in_q1_not_q2)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line

# In Q2 but not in Q1
account_in_q2_not_q1 = (
    []
)  # creating a list to store the accounts that are in Q2 but not in Q1
for i in range(1, len(data_q2)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 2
    if (
        data_q2[i][2] not in account_in_both
    ):  # checking if the account is not in both quarters
        account_in_q2_not_q1.append(data_q2[i][2])  # appending the account to the list

print("Account in Q2 but not in Q1", account_in_q2_not_q1)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line

# In which both list are same
all_rows_are_same_in_both = (
    []
)  # creating a list to store the rows that are in both quarters
for i in range(1, len(data_q1)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 1
    for j in range(1, len(data_q2)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 2
        if data_q1[i] == data_q2[j]:  # checking if the rows are same
            all_rows_are_same_in_both.append(
                data_q1[i]
            )  # appending the row to the list

print("All rows are same in both", all_rows_are_same_in_both)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line

# In which rows are in q1 but not in q2
rows_in_q1_not_q2 = []  # creating a list to store the rows that are in Q1 but not in Q2
for i in range(1, len(data_q1)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 1
    if (
        data_q1[i] not in all_rows_are_same_in_both
    ):  # checking if the row is not in both quarters
        rows_in_q1_not_q2.append(data_q1[i])  # appending the row to the list

print("Rows in Q1 but not in Q2", rows_in_q1_not_q2)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line

# In which rows are in q2 but not in q1
rows_in_q2_not_q1 = []  # creating a list to store the rows that are in Q2 but not in Q1
for i in range(1, len(data_q2)):  # iterating through the list for Quarter 2
    if (
        data_q2[i] not in all_rows_are_same_in_both
    ):  # checking if the row is not in both quarters
        rows_in_q2_not_q1.append(data_q2[i])  # appending the row to the list

print("Rows in Q2 but not in Q1", rows_in_q2_not_q1)  # printing the list
print("\n\n")  # printing a new line
```

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: You still have 6 screenshots in the question.

Comment: i suggest you check out the `pandas` library (`pip install pandas`). it is the primary python library for working with dataframes (think excel or sql tables), including reading, transforming, and writing.

Comment: Thanks, updated again. Weird it didn't save that time. May need a bit of format in excel

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating this with the nested loops.

Simply do a list comprehension that loops through one list, and checks if the element is/is not in the other list:

```
account_in_q1 = [x for x in list(data_q1['Account']) if x not in list(data_q2['Account'])]
account_in_q2 = [x for x in list(data_q2['Account']) if x not in list(data_q1['Account'])]
account_in_both = [x for x in list(data_q1['Account']) if x in list(data_q2['Account'])]
```

But even with that, as it sounds like you want to put this into a table perhaps, I'd just use `pandas`, and merge using the `'outer'` join, include the indicator on the merged dataframe, and filter out that way.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

path_quarter_1 = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Quarter_1.csv")  # path to the csv file
path_quarter_2 = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Quarter_2.csv")  # path to the csv file

data_q1 = pd.read_csv(path_quarter_1)
data_q2 = pd.read_csv(path_quarter_2)


cols = list(data_q1.columns)
merged = data_q1.merge(data_q2, how='outer', on=cols, indicator=True)

# In Q1 but not in Q2
in_q1 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
q1_accounts = list(in_q1['Account'])
print("Rows in Q1 but not in Q2", q1_accounts)


# In Q2 but not in Q1
in_q2 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
q2_accounts = list(in_q2['Account'])
print("Rows in Q2 but not in Q1", q2_accounts)

# In which both list are same
in_both = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both']
both_accounts = list(in_both['Account'])
print("All rows are same in both", both_accounts)
```

**Output:**

```
Rows in Q1 but not in Q2 [1002, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1013]
Rows in Q2 but not in Q1 [10002, 1015]
All rows are same in both [1001, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008]
```

To see where different accounts are "linked" together:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import numpy as np

path_quarter_1 = os.path.join('D:/test/', "Quarter_1.csv")  # path to the csv file
path_quarter_2 = os.path.join('D:/test/', "Quarter_2.csv")  # path to the csv file

data_q1 = pd.read_csv(path_quarter_1)
data_q2 = pd.read_csv(path_quarter_2)


cols = [x for x in data_q1.columns if x != 'Account']
merged = data_q1.merge(data_q2, how='outer', on=cols, indicator=True)

for col in ['Account_x', 'Account_y']:
    merged[col] = merged[col].fillna('')

def combine_columns(row):
    combined = list(set([row['Account_x'], row['Account_y']]))
    combined = [x for x in combined if x != '']
    combined = [str(int(x)) for x in combined]
    return combined 

merged['Account'] = merged.apply(lambda row: combine_columns(row), axis=1)

# In Q1 but not in Q2
in_q1 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only']
q1_accounts = list(in_q1['Account'])
print("Rows in Q1 but not in Q2", q1_accounts)


# In Q2 but not in Q1
in_q2 = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'right_only']
q2_accounts = list(in_q2['Account'])
print("Rows in Q2 but not in Q1", q2_accounts)

# In which both list are same
in_both = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both']
both_accounts = list(in_both['Account'])
print("All rows are same in both", both_accounts)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! is it possible, to have the accounts with the other data. So for example account in Q1 but not in Q2 '1002' has all the other elements from the other columns?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: So are you saying all coulmns match except the "Acounts"?

Comment: No, actually I'm looking for a table instead of just the list of accounts. So I consider the accounts as like a unique id. it's nice that the list has accounts, but is it possible to make a table instead and include accounts, but the other columns as well?

Comment: The tables are there. They are stored as `in_q1`, `in_q2`, `in_both`. Just print those with `print(in_q1)`, etc.